# Installation of Matlab R2012A in Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, installation, matlab

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I tried to install Matlab R2012A in it. At first I installed "ia32-libs" and then I tried to run it using the following command:
 sudo /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install -glnx86 -v
But it showed      sudo: /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install: command not found
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have to make the install script executable:

```
chmod +x /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/install
```

And probably you also need to make executable java:

```
chmod +x /media/MATHWORKS_R2012A/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java
```

Normally you don't need to specify the architecture (-glnx86) to install matlab, unless you want to force a 32 bit Matlab on a 64 bit machine